# Loop inside Laravel return view('pageName', [ loop] gives me an error

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to use a **loop insinde laravel `return view()`** to pass mutltiple variables. So that no need to hard code them and this list has 30 items and it always select 8 values randomly. So this is my code

```
 return view ( 'shop.landing' , [
            for($z = 0 ; $z <8 ;$z++){
                'productMatchesToMasterCategory' => ($masterCategoryList[$z]['name'].$productMatchesToMasterCategory);
            }
            'tomorrow' => Carbon::tomorrow () ,
```

This is the snap

[image: snap]

So could anyone please tell whats wrong in my code or is it not allowed to use a loop inside `view()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a loop inside array syntax.
The solution is to build the array outside, and then pass it as a parameter. I'm not sure exactly the structure you are looking for, but something like this:

```php
$data = [];

for ($z = 0; $z < 8; $z++) {
    $data[] = ($masterCategoryList[$z]['name'] . $productMatchesToMasterCategory);
}

return view('shop.landing', [
    'productMatchesToMasterCategory' => $data,
    'tomorrow' => Carbon::tomorrow(),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it before return the view:

```php
$productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray = [];
for($z = 0; $z < 8; $z++) {
    $productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray[] = ($masterCategoryList[$z]['name'].$productMatchesToMasterCategory);     
}

return view('shop.landing', [
    'productMatchesToMasterCategory' => $productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray
    //Other variables here
]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to get the array of random 8 element before returning the view.

```html
$productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray = [];
foreach($masterCategoryList as $z){
    $productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray[] = ($z['name'].$productMatchesToMasterCategory);
}
$random_Array=array_rand($productMatchesToMasterCategoryArray,8);
return view('shop.landing', [
    'productMatchesToMasterCategory' => $random_Array,
    'tomorrow' => Carbon::tomorrow(),
]);
```